# WPF Xaml - Align Image to Right

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just starting out with xaml.

I have the following:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Compare"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Path to Access DB:"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Margin="3"
                           Width="120"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtPathToAccess"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             Height="23"
                             Margin="3"
                             Text="{Binding PathToAccessDb}"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Width="800" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnFileSearch"
                            Content="..."
                            Width="20"
                            Height="20"
                            Command="{Binding AccessFileSearchCommand}" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnComparePiToAccess"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Content="Compare Pi to Access"
                            Width="150"
                            Height="20"
                            Command="{Binding CompareCommandPiToAccess}" />
                    <Image Source="/Images/drax_logo.jpg" 
                           Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
```

How can I get the image to align to the right edge of the stack panel? I want the labels and buttons at the left of the screen (row) and the image at the right.

Comment: `StackPanel` causes all elements within to use minimum possible space. If you want to fill to the maximum edge of the Panel, you can use a `DockPanel` which has the option to tell where a certain element will dock or use a `Grid` which has fixed columns and rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this by using stackpanel. Instead, create a grid with 2 columns and put image in second column and set `HorizontalAlignment` to right.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Compare"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Path to Access DB:"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Margin="3"
                       Width="120"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPathToAccess"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Height="23"
                         Margin="3"
                         Text="{Binding PathToAccessDb}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Width="800" />
        <Button x:Name="btnFileSearch"
                        Content="..."
                        Width="20"
                        Height="20"
                        Command="{Binding AccessFileSearchCommand}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnComparePiToAccess"
                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        Content="Compare Pi to Access"
                        Width="150"
                        Height="20"
                        Command="{Binding CompareCommandPiToAccess}" />

    </StackPanel>

    <Image Grid.Column="1" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Source="/Images/drax_logo.jpg" 
           Width="100" />
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't actually need two columns. Horizontal Alignment also works in a single column.

Comment: Yeap. Its just one of the ways. Of course, this can be done using dockpanel as well.